# Check values of a column and return the row

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create a query that checks my table and if it finds a value that does not match my parameter, return the row.

For example this is table A:

[image]

I have  another table (table B), that contains the value 1.2 that I will use as my parameter.

So, in this example, I need to return all the rows that are not 1.2

The value in Table B, can change, so I need to get it in real time (with a select)

I've been trying different approaches, but with no luck so far.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from   t
where  sv not in(select sv from t2)
```

| sv | client |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1 | john |
| 1.1 | ron |
| 1.1 | george |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2FrS1G8p?hide=2)